# CheckBox List in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have this:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'search-form',
    'method' => 'get',
    'action' => ['/directory/index'],
    'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal'],
    'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
    'enableClientValidation' => true,
    'validateOnBlur' => false,
]); ?>

.........................................................

<?php foreach ($model->my_getStatusOptions() as $value => $title): ?>
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <?= Html::activeCheckbox($model, 'status', [
                 'class' => 'custom-control-input',
                  'value' => $value,
                   'label' => false,
                   'uncheck' => false,
                  ]) ?>
                  <span class="custom-control-label">
                    <?= $title ?>
                  </span>
    </label>
<?php endforeach; ?>



........................................................

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

This is what my_getStatusOptions() function returns:

```
<?php print_r($model->my_getStatusOptions()); ?>
Array ( [0] => value0 [1] => value1 [2] => value2 [3] => value3 [4] => value4 [5] => value5 )
```

I need to search in database based on checked checkboxes and I'm facing this issue:
After selecting multiple "status" checkboxes, when I press submit button, only the first selected checkbox remains selected.

In the same form I have another checkbox like the following, and when the submit button is pressed the checkbox keeps its value(checked/unchecked)

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'online')->checkbox() ?>
```

Comment: Your $model->status is a single value attribute and not an array and it will not contain all checked checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `activeCheckboxList` like follows:

```
<?= Html::activeCheckboxList($model, 'status', $model->my_getStatusOptions())
```

Comment: Thank you but now the searching url is at follow: ....&status=&status%5B%5D=2&status%5B%5D=3 

How can I search by multiple checked statuses if I have this:

managers/UserManager.php 
if ($model->status) {
                $query->status($model->status);
            }


models/query/UserQuery.php 
public function status($status)
    {
        return $this->andWhere('profile.status = ???');
    }